# how to provide values to awk from external source?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have the follwing script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# this script splits a big CSV file, by 2nd column.
# the results will be as many CSV files as distinct values exist in original file, in the 2nd column.

PO_list=$(awk -F";" '{print $2}' test.csv | awk '!seen[$0]++')

for i in $PO_list;
    do
        cat test.csv | grep $i > "fisier_"$i.csv
    done
```

It is working fine but I want to not restrict the user by hard-coding the certain column into the script but to let him to choose the column number to be used for split.
For this I want to give the column number as parameter into the command which is calling the shell script. For example, in this moment, I am executing the script as:

```
abc$ ./test.sh
```

but i want to execute it like

```
abc$ ./test.sh 2
```

where "2" to be passed as parameter to awk command, repalcing the "$2" value from it.

Can someone to help with this, please?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass variables to awk using the `-v` switch:

```
awk -v col=2 '{print $col}'
```

would do what you want.

So in your script, you can use the value of `$1`, (the first argument to the script) like:

```
PO_list=$(awk -F";" -v col="$1" '!seen[$col]++ {print $col}' test.csv)
```

Note that I've also combined your two awk commands into one.

I think that you can actually do the whole thing in awk:

```
awk -F";" -v col="$1" '{ print > "fisier_"$col".csv" }' test.csv
```

Comment: Without the quotes, `;` would be interpreted by the shell.

Comment: My fault, it should be `-F\;`

Comment: Thank you Tom Fenech. It is working just fine with `-F";"`
I was using you idea and now it is working very nice.

Comment: @fedorqui in the original script, the OP is producing a list of the distinct values in the column, then looping through each value and using grep to filter out the lines in the original file. Unless I'm mistaken, the single line of awk does the same thing, doesn't it?